# Построение доверительных интервалов в MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Суть задачи такова: нужно построить график измеренной величины.
У меня уже есть перенесённые в MATLAB переменные.

Первая переменная: массив параметров x размером в 30 точек.
Вторая переменная: двумерный массив y размера 40x30.

Т.е. каждому значению `x(i)` у меня соответствует одномерный столбец намеренных значений `y(:, i)`.
Я могу функцией `mean(y(:, i))` подсчитать среднее `y_mean(i)` для каждого `x(i)` (результат измерений - случайная величина с неизвестным распределением). И потом на этих двух массивах можно строить график.
Однако мне ещё надобно построить доверительные интервалы.

Весь вопрос в том, как это сделать?

Я смотрел help для функции `confint` и объекта `fit`, но так и не разобрался. На массиве реализаций я могу посчитать дисперсию и потом вытащить доверительный интервал из распределения Стьюдента. Однако мне хочется, чтобы MATLAB сделал это вместо меня.

Куда нужно смотреть в help'e?

*И ещё:* будет очень здорово если эти доверительные интервалы будут выведены на график, типа точка и возле неё такая штучка буквой T. Типа вот какая ошибка возможна по оси Y.
Как это сделать?
Можно ли это сделать обычным `plot()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> будет очень здорово если эти доверительные интервалы будут выведены на
>   график, типа точка и возле неё такая штучка буквой T. Типа вот какая
>   ошибка возможна по оси Y. Как это сделать? Можно ли это сделать
>   обычным plot()?

Для этого нужно воспользоваться функцией `errorbar`. Нужно будет четыре массива: массив значений по X, значений по Y, ошибки вверх по Y, ошибки вниз по Y. В help'e можно дополнительно посмотреть как задать симметричные ошибки.

И кроме всего прочего, `errorbar` по-прежнему поддерживает задание стиля линий (цвета, маркеров и т.п.)